# React-dnd what does $splice do

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am reading [an example of the React-dnd project](https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/blob/master/examples/04%20Sortable/Simple/Container.js#L48):

```
moveCard(dragIndex, hoverIndex) {
    const { cards } = this.state;
    const dragCard = cards[dragIndex];

    this.setState(update(this.state, {
      cards: {
        $splice: [
          [dragIndex, 1],
          [hoverIndex, 0, dragCard]
        ]
      }
    }));}
```

Is this $splice the same one explained [on this page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)?

Could anybody explain what does this chunk of code do? The `$splice` function is very confusion to me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's basically an immutable version of plain splice functions such as

```
newcards.splice(dragIndex, 1); // removing what you are dragging.
newcards.splice(hoverIndex, 0, dragCard); // inserting it into hoverIndex.
```

Instead of directly manipulating the target array, those Immutability Helpers are helping you update the state by creating and assigning a new state.

Answer (score 6):

Took me a while to understand. Here is step by step explanation in conventional arrow function

```
  moveCard = (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
    // list of cards
    let newcards = this.state.cards; 

    // dragCard is card we are dragging
    let dragCard = newcards[dragIndex]; 

   // removing this dragCard from array
    newcards.splice(dragIndex, 1);

     // insert dragCard at hover position
    newcards.splice(hoverIndex, 0, dragCard); 

    // update State
    this.setState({
      cards: newcards
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this version a lot more.

Comment: Can someone answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64913638/how-to-swap-two-cards-without-changing-position-other-cards