# How to swap two cards without changing position other cards

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I have images in grid form something like this
[image]

I am well aware of react dnd and it uses hover to get the positions and swap accordingly.

> What I want

: Swap 1 with 4 and 4 with 1
[image]

> What is happening:

While moving image 1 I am hovering it from 2 and 3 so the images in between are getting swapped here

[image]

I have modified my moveCard function to match my requirement.

```
const moveCard = useCallback((dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
      const dragCard = cards;
      [dragCard[dragIndex], dragCard[hoverIndex]] = [
        dragCard[hoverIndex],
        dragCard[dragIndex]
      ];
      setCards([...dragCard]);
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated.
All I want is to swap only 2 images that I am dragging and which I dropping, the rest images should not change their position.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I've found. My state is more complex, so I use [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) which provides `update` function below

```
const moveCard = useCallback((dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
        setCards((prevCards) =>
            update(prevCards, {
                $splice: [
                    [dragIndex, 1], // remove the card we're dragging
                    [dragIndex, 0, prevCards[hoverIndex]], // put the card we're hovering over in it's place
                    [hoverIndex, 1], // remove the card we're hovering over
                    [hoverIndex, 0, prevCards[dragIndex]], // insert dragged card into hover cards's position
                ],
            }),
        )
}, [])
```